# React validation of dynamic checkboxes

Tags: reactjs

I have 7 checkboxes that are rendered within a map method.. each checkbox has a question and when all checkboxes are checked, a button should be activated.. can someone please tell me how can I validate this using useState() hook.. I know how to do this with one checkbox, but I don't know how to handle multiple checkboxes that are rendered within a map method. A code example should be very helpful. Any help will be appreciated.

```
const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

{ questions.map(q => (
                  <input
                    type={q.radio ? "radio" : "checkbox"}
                    onClick={() => setIsChecked(!isChecked)}
                    value={isChecked}
                    id={option.id}
                    value={option.value}
                    name={`${q.name}`}
                  />
```

There are 7 checkboxes rendered with this map method. How should I handle the state in this case?

Comment: Can you share your component code and how you are storing each checkbox state?

Comment: I've modified the question. So basically, this is my problem, I don't know how to handle the state in this case, for each input rendered with the map method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can model your state to fit your usecase. For a list of 7 checkboxes you can have an array with 7 values:

```
const [checked, setChecked] = useState([false, false, false, false, false, false, false])
```

The when a check box is clicked:

```
{ questions.map((q, i) => (
              <input
                type={q.radio ? "radio" : "checkbox"}
                onClick={() => setChecked(current => {
                   const newState = [...current]
                   newState[i] = !newState[i]
                   return newState
                } )}
                value={checked[i]}
                id={option.id}
                value={option.value}
                name={`${q.name}`}
              />
```

To know if all are checked you can defined a variable:

```
const areAllChecked = checked.every(Boolean)
```

Comment: This approach doesn't make much sense. Sure it works but what if you have 50 checkboxes, are you going to declare an array with 50 false booleans inside?

Comment: As I've said - it depends on the usecase - for 50 I would use a different approach. For the OP's usecase I think an array makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 0):

If your questions are dynamic list you can use below approach:

```js
const QUESTIONS = ["Do you use Stackoverflow?", "Do you asked a question?"];

function Confirmation({ data }) {
  const [questions, setQuestions] = React.useState(
    data.map((question, index) => {
      return { id: index, text: question, checked: false };
    })
  );

  const handleClick = (id, checked) => {
    const newQuestions = [...questions];
    const index = newQuestions.findIndex((q) => q.id === id);
    newQuestions[index].checked = checked;

    setQuestions(newQuestions);
  };

  const isButtonDisabled = questions.some((q) => q.checked === false);

  return (
    <div>
      {questions.map((question) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <input
            key={question.id}
            name={`question-${question.id}`}
            type="checkbox"
            checked={question.checked}
            onClick={(e) => handleClick(question.id, e.target.checked)}
          />
          <label htmlFor={`question-${question.id}`}>{question.text}</label>
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
      <button disabled={isButtonDisabled}>Confirm</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Confirmation data={QUESTIONS} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to thedude's answer, you can dynamically adjust the `checked` array based on changes to your questions array so that you don't have to manually maintain the initial states or remember to sync it to the new length of questions if it changes.

```
const [checked, setChecked] = useState([])

const arrLength = questions.length;
useEffect(() => {
  setChecked(() => (
    Array(arrLength).fill().map((_, i) => checked[i] || false)
  ));
}, [arrLength]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following your example of mapping over your questions.
You could load those questions in `useState` and append the check value to them.

Click the **Run Code Snippet** below to see it working.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const App = props => {
  const { questions } = props;
  const [state, setState] = useState(null);
  
  const onChangeCheckbox = index => event => {
    const newState = [...state];
    newState[index].checked = !newState[index].checked;
    setState(newState);
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setState(questions.map(i => ({...i, checked: false }) ));
  }, [questions]);
  
  // Not loaded yet
  if (!state) return <div></div>; 
  
  return <div>
    {state && state.length > 0 && <div>
       {state.map((i, k) => <p key={`question-${k}`}>
        <label><input onChange={onChangeCheckbox(k)} type="checkbox" name={i.name} checked={i.checked} />&nbsp;{i.question}</label>
       </p>)}
    </div>}
    <hr />
    <p><small>Debug</small></p>
    <pre><code>{JSON.stringify(state, null, ' ')}</code></pre>
  </div>;
};

const questions = [
{
  name: 'cyborg',
  question: 'Are you a cyborg?'
},
{
  name: 'earth',
  question: 'Do you live on earth?'
},
{
  name: 'alien',
  question: 'Are you from another planet?'
}
];


ReactDOM.render(<App questions={questions} />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

pre {
  background: #efefef;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the key param to give each checkbox an identifier so it can be modified.

```
const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
     compareList()
        
    })
    { questions.map((q,i) => (
                      <input
                        type={q.radio ? "radio" : "checkbox"}
                        onClick={() => setIsChecked(!isChecked[i])}
                        value={isChecked[i]}
                        id={option.id}
                        value={option.value}
                        name={`${q.name}`}
                        key=i
                      />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use controlled input the solution might be like this:

```
const initialState = [
  {
    name: "Check option 1",
    checked: false
  },
  {
    name: "Check option 2",
    checked: false
  },
]

const App = () => {
  const [checkboxes, setCheckboxes] = useState(initialState)
  const [quizFinished, setQuizFinished] = useState(false)
  // the useEffect checks if all questions are completed
  useEffect(()=>{
    setQuizFinished(checkboxes.reduce((acc, cbx) => acc && cbx.checked, true))
  }, [checkboxes])
  
  function handleChange(e) {
    setCheckboxes(
      checkboxes.map(cbx => cbx.name === e.target.name ? {...cbx, checked:!cbx.checked} : cbx)
    )
  }
  return (
    <>
      {checkboxes.map(cbx => <Checkbox name={cbx.name} checked={cbx.checked} onChange={handleChange}/>)}
      {quizFinished && <button>Finish</button>}
    </>
  )
}

const Checkbox = ({name, checked, onChange}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <label>
        {name}
        <input type="checkbox" name={name} checked={checked} onChange={onChange} />
      </label>
      <br/>
    </>
  )
}
```